# How to change content of p-element with my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried various codes I found online, but I wasn’t able to combine it with my code.

[image]

Sequence:

1. Website-User hovers the book-picture and the whole book slides into the viewport.
2. The visitor clicks on the picture and the background-images changes
3. **Missing:** I would like to change the content of the p-Element from **1/2** (page) to **2/2** (page), if the background-color had changed.

How can I do this?

```js
// MY CSS

#img_tulip-book-01 {
    position: absolute;
    background: url("../pictures/tulip-book-1.png") no-repeat center right;
    background-size: contain!important;
    top: 700px;
    left: -550px;
    height: 700px;
    width: 480px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 200;
}


.img_tulip-book-02 {
    background: url("../pictures/tulip-book-2.png") 
    no-repeat center right!important;
    background-size: contain!important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```css
// MY HTML

            <div id="img_tulip-book-01">
                <p class="italic2 black" style="position: absolute; right: 0px">1/2</p>

            </div>
```

```html
// MY jQUERY

<script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#img_tulip-book-01').mouseenter(function() {
                $(this).animate({
                            left: '+=280px'},
                        {
                            duration: "slow",
                            easing: "easein"
                        });

            });
            $('#img_tulip-book-01').mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    left: '-=280px'
                });

            });


            $('#img_tulip-book-01').click(function() {

                $(this).toggleClass('img_tulip-book-02');

            });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: First thing first you have a syntax error. It should be _ 'left':'-250px' _

Comment: @bayblade567 why should this be a syntax error? It's a string and it passes a variable to jQuery's animate which is legitimate. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#img_tulip-book-01').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('img_tulip-book-02');
   var pageNumber = $(this).find("p").text()
   if (pageNumber == "1/2") {
     $(this).find("p").text("2/2");
   } else {
     $(this).find("p").text("1/2");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find("p").text("2/2");
```

This line will do exactly that.

It should be in:

```
$('#img_tulip-book-01').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('img_tulip-book-02');
   $(this).find("p").text("2/2");
});
```

Comment: Hello Mouser, thank you for your quick response. Unfortunately this solution works just once. After I clicked a third time on it the p-Element won’t change. It just gets reseted, if the mouse leaves.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/397267/problem.gif

Comment: @horrible-coder Yes that is what I could deduce from your posted code and question. There needs to be a counter or something.

Comment: You'd actually want use an if statement. If the <p> element contains 1/2, set it to 2/2, and vice versa.